# How to get FileOutputFormat statistics like record-count, bytes-written, etc in spark?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

In Hadoop when I use a `FileOutputFormat` I get a report at the end describing the number of records, bytes written, etc in the logs (I think it is the job-tracker log).

Now in Spark I'm using the same `FileOutputFormat` via the `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset` method:

```
myPairRdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(config);
```

However I cannot figure out how to collect statistics from the `FileOutputFormat`.

In the Spark application, I'm using accumulators as counters to get some statistics but I want to collect stats in the FileOutputFormat and report it at the end.

I'm even willing to write my own `FileOutputFormat` & `RecordWriter` delegator which would count the records and delegate the actual writing of records to the (internal) `FileOutputFormat`.  I'm a bit worried about running counts in a user-defined record-writer since I'm not sure how to collect the data from all the writers across all the tasks.

What's the best way to collect this info?